# Custom submit handler: how to create node?

Tags: forms

I created a form_node_alter for a content type called "banner" and I made a custom submit handler named "mymodule_check_submit_handler()".
Everything is ok, I can do what I want in the submit handler function but I don't know how to create the node of type "banner" once I executed my custom code.

Searching for a solution I found this code:

```
$values = $form_state->getValues();
$node = entity_create('node', $values);
$node->save();
```

But now I got this error: Error: Call to a member function getValues() on array in mymodule_check_submit_handler()

How can I create the node in my custom submit handler?

Comment: What is your Drupal version ?

Comment: I might misunderstand, but if you need to check the provided data (as your function name implies) wouldn't you be better off adding a custom validation callback and just leaving the regular submit? Would seem like a cleaner solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

After some searches I post the solution to myself!

This is the right code to use:

```
$values = $form_state['values'];
$node = entity_create('node', $values);
$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
node_save($node);
```